# What is the tie breaker in the weekly user reputation leagues?

Tags: discussion, reputation-leagues

Looking at the weekly user reputation leagues, I see that users are ranked based on how much reputation they have gained during that week.  However, I see that there are no ties in the rankings; each place is assigned to one user only.  So how are these ties in weekly reputation broken?

Looking at the first page of results from [Sports last week](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/189/week/sports/2014-02-02), I can see that the answer is not:

- Total reputation for the user
- last week's rank
- change in place from last week
- user number

What is the tie breaker?

Comment: It's very possibly "arbitrary".